# Programmatically populated UITableView can't fill the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

I am following this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/ which shows how to create an `UITableView` and populate it programmatically. All's good, it works.

Now, I am trying to make the table fill the screen: regardless of the device or orientation. I did this:

[image]

But now the table view simply does not appear in my screen (I imagine it is somewhere far away due to a problem with the constraints?).

There really isn't much code for me to show. I literally just placed an `UITableView` into the interface builder, and followed that tutorial to set the delegate to my view controller. The methods would be

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Where `tableData` is an array with 16 strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove all constraints, then select your `tableView` and add their again and press *Add 4 constraints*. Be sure, you don't have some ambiguity.

[image]